# Building pipeline in GitHub Actions for a WINUI application

Tags: uwp, github-actions, pipeline, cicd, winui

I'm trying to create my own pipeline in GitHub Actions.
All though I'm having issues on the build action with the following message:

`Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(27,5): error NETSDK1134: Building a solution with a specific RuntimeIdentifier is not supported. If you would like to publish for a single RID, specifiy the RID at the individual project level instead. [D:\a\it_project_testGA\it_project_testGA\InternshipTool.sln]`

When I double check this in my .csproj files from my solution I don't have any code like this:
`<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`

I totally don't have an idea how to fix this. Can the community help me?
The current pipeline I'm using.

```
name: IT Project InternshipTool

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "development" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "development" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check .NET version
      run: dotnet --version
      
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Install .NET SDK Version
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.x.x
      
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
      
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --runtime win-x64 --property:EnableWindowsTargeting=true
      
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --configuration Release --collect:"XPLAT Code Coverage"
```

Creating a pipeline in GitHub Actions

Comment: I am using the following parameter when running dotnet build:
`-f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -r win10-x64 -p:Platform=x64 -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 --self-contained`  - I would think that either the -f setting or the property parameter for Platform and/or RuntimeIdentifierOverride is missing in your command.

Comment: @Brutusske: Build the project instead of the solution? Or remove the `--runtime` option from the `build` command.